# Scattermapbox clickData callback is not triggerd when unselect item in map

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I'm using [Scattermapbox](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/) for a project. In Scattermapbox it is possible to enable the option 'clickmode='event+select'. This makes it possible to trigger a callback by using clickData. Unfortunately I only get a callback when selecting and not when deselecting. is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with a **callback**

- respond to `clickData` with the **figure State**
- inspect `selectedpoints` and add / remove as appropriate

#### complete working example

```
import dash, json, io, requests
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# get some public addressess - hospitals.  data that has GPS lat / lon
dfhos = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get("http://media.nhschoices.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text
    ),
    sep="¬",
    engine="python",
).loc[:, ["OrganisationName", "Latitude", "Longitude"]]

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(dfhos, lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude").update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "open-street-map",
        "zoom": 6,
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "r": 0},
).update_traces(selected={"marker":{"color":"red"}})

# create the dash app
# app = dash.Dash()
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [
        dash.dcc.Graph(id="map", figure=fig),
        dash.html.Div(id="outDiv")
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("map","figure"),
    [Input("map", "clickData")],
    [State("map", "figure")]
)
def mapClick(clickData, fig):
    fig = go.Figure(fig)
    if clickData:
        p = clickData["points"][0]["pointIndex"]
        pa = fig.data[0]["selectedpoints"]
        pa = tuple() if not pa else pa
        if p in pa:
            pa = [sp for sp in pa if sp!=p]
        else:
            pa = pa + (p,)
        
        fig.data[0]["selectedpoints"] = pa
        
    return fig

app.run_server(mode="inline")
```